# How to have more than one examples in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using the doxywizard. Under Expert tab, in Input item-list, at EXAMPLE_PATH, I have included two paths, that lead to one .cpp file, each. However, in the generated documentation, I see only the one, regardless of order.

In the Doxyfile, I see this:

```
EXAMPLE_PATH           = ../../../Inria/rkd/Samaras/final/code/main_boost.cpp \
                         ../../../Inria/rkd/Samaras/final/code/main.cpp
```

What am I missing?

If there is a solution by editing the Doxyfile directly, I would be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXAMPLE_PATH lists the directories where you store your example files. 
If you want to add an example for a specific class, you have reference the in the header file of your class.

EXAMPLE_PATH           = ../../../Inria/rkd/Samaras/final/code

```
/** \example main_boost.cpp
 * This is an example of how to use main_boost.
 */

/** \example main.cpp
 * This is an example of how to use main.
 */
```

see more info here: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample

Comment: Correct. I thought of that too, but then I thought that main.cpp was listed normally in the examples, without the relevant comments. Probably the reason was that I had the mainpage there.